# Char array not reading input correctly

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, char

I was tasked with making a program that has a char array filled with the correct answers to a 10 questions test. I made an array that was filled with the users answers and was supposed to check the user answers with the test answers and give an output of pass or fail given the user input. The code compiles and I can enter in the 10 chars however no matter what chars I enter in, the output is always 10 answers were incorrect out of 10.

I have been stumped for the past few hours trying to figure this out and was hoping for some help here.

Here is the code snippet:

```
     //Part 2
    char[] correctAnswers = {'b', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'}; //Char arrays
    char[] studentAnswers = new char[10];

    System.out.println("What are the students 10 answers?"); //Getting student answers

    for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++)
        studentAnswers = scan.next().toCharArray();

    int points = 0; //Used to calculate pass or fail

    for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++);

    int j = 0; //Used to identify each element in the array

    if (correctAnswers[j] == studentAnswers[j]) //Checks each answer with the correct answers and adds 1 point if it is true
    {
        points++;
        j++;
    }
    else {
        j++;
    }

     if (points >= 8) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! \nYou have passed exam.");
        System.out.println("Total number of correct answers: " + points); //print points
        System.out.println("Total number of incorrect answers: " + (correctAnswers.length - points)); //10 - points would equal the remaining amount of points available which would be how many were missed.
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you have not passed the exam!");
        System.out.println("Total number of correct answers: " + points);
        System.out.println("Total number of incorrect answers: " + (correctAnswers.length - points));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++)
    studentAnswers = scan.next().toCharArray();
```

1. I think you should remove the first line. It appears twice. Assuming you read in all 10 answers as 1 String.
2. And then use `i` everywhere instead of `j`, it is superfluous (remove the declaration of `j` and `j++`, so the `else` which becomes empty can be deleted too).
3. Additionally you need to put braces `{}` after the `for` and before the output (i.e. before checking the total points). If you put a semicolon `;` after the `for` then you are doing nothing x times.

I see why you used `j`: because `i` wasn't defined. It lives only in the loop (which consisted of the empty, skip or "do nothing" command: a lonely semicolon). When you add the `{}` (see 3.) then `i` lives in between those braces.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, however now I am getting an array out of bounds error in the output?

Comment: @Tyler only if you enter less than or more than 10 characters, I guess.

Comment: I enter in exactly 10 which is the size of the array then I get that error. Im very confused as to fix this error I have never encountered it.

Comment: @Tyler maybe you need to put a .trim() after next or use nextLine, could be a custom class, so I don't know. Either do a System.out.printn of the array sizes or use a good development environment, e.g. eclipse, set a breakpoint and check out what's going on.